# How can I use a modifier key with the Razer Naga?

Tags: macros, razer-keyboard

I have a macro that I wrote with Razer synapse 2.0. I want to trigger this macro whenever I hold down shift and then hit '4' on the side of my Naga.

Is this possible to do with Razer synapse?